# What does a Galilean transformation actually mean?

Tags: reference-frames, inertial-frames, definition, galilean-relativity

What does a [Galilean transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation) actually mean? I'm having trouble defining the equation for displacement shifts $x'=x-vt$. Does it mean that to any event $C$ the displacement in the primed coordinate system is the displacement to $C$ minus the velocity times time of the primed coordinate system? If so then don't both coordinate systems have to be at the same event at $t = 0$? I don't see this specified anywhere I look. Also, how does it directly show invariance of the euclidean distance between two points?

Comment: It's a pain to carefully specify the conditions under which the simple version of the transformation applies; most authors only do so once, and in less formal writing many elide it completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three question marks in your question. Addressing each of them separately, in chronological order;

1. Yes, provided the primed co-ordinate system is the moving one and it is moving along the positive direction of the x-axis.
2. Yes, they have to be; that is the initial condition of Galilean transformation.
3. Euclidean distance between $2$ points, ($x_1,y_1$) and ($x_2,y_2$) is given by: $d=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$. Apply the Galilean transformation and check that the form of the expression written above remains the same.

Comment: How can i apply number 3. without using circular reasoning? i.e. $x'^2=(x-vt)^2$? I know that translations don't affect distance but i want prove that this transformation is necessary in order to preserve euclidean distance. It all seems so simple yet i get stuck in this spiral of confusion when i overthink it.

Comment: Sorry, your first line is unclear to me. Where exactly are you finding circular reasoning? And what do you want to show: E dist is invariant under GT or that the invariance of E dist requires GT? The latter is not true in the absolute sense, a Lorentz transformation works fine.

Comment: well, can you please help me along and work through number 3? I don't understand how and where it should apply. The latter should be true since lorentz transformations don't preserve euclidean distance and we assume time does not transform between frames?

Comment: I cannot work out the mathematics since it is against homework policy. But I'll give hint. You know that $x'=x-vt$, so $x=x'+vt'$ since $t=t'$ in GT. So $x_1=x_1'+vt'$ and so on. Put these in the expression for d and see that the form remains same, the unprimed becomes primed. Just that. As for Lorentz T, notice the use of the word 'absolute' and that euclidean space is defined for n dimensions.

Comment: *"Yes, provided the primed co-ordinate system is the moving one and it is moving along the positive direction of the x-axis."* Rather misses the point of relativity (even the Galilean variety). As written the primped frame is move at $v$ *with respect to* the unprimed frame. But it is just as correct to say that the unprimed frame moves at $-v$ WRT to primed frame. And indeed you'll find the transformation equation written with the signs reversed in some sources.

Comment: @dmckee Yes. Of course. I just mentioned the condition. It can always be interpreted in different ways from different frames, provided the phenomena remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a [generalized Galilean transformation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.1384.pdf), which includes "offsets" (static rotation and spatial and temporal shifts) between coordinate frames.